# Use functions/classes from another directory

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I am running `Windows`, `Anaconda` and `PyCharm` if that matters.

My directory looks as follows:

```
\MyMainDirectory
    \FunctionsLibrary
         ClassA.py
         ClassB.py
         functionA.py
         functionB.py
    \Project A
        main.py
    \Project B
        main.py
```

How can I with this directory setup use e.g. `functionA.py` and `ClassA.py` etc in my file `e.g. \Project A\main.py, \Project B\main.py` etc?

I have some common functions & classes that I would like to use in my separate projects "Project A" and "Project B".

*Please note that "Project A" and "Project B" are two different projects in PyCharm.*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't you use them if you include those files in your "Project A\main.py"?

Comment: Include the files in the folder? Ideally not since then if I have to edit e.g. functionA.py then I need to edit it in several folders.

Comment: Is this setup limited to pycharm, or you plan to use it somewhere in production?

Comment: It will be in production but maybe in a compiled way, not sure yet. Why do you ask? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the best solution (at least for my application but probably for other people as well) which is to create a package (module) of the class or set of functions that is used by different project.

Then just install the package (module) that you have built. I simply followed this guide which works great.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Please note: You do not have to upload the code to github, it is also possible to just have an offline version of your package.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can include paths using 'sys'

```
# In your main.py
import sys
sys.path.append("../FunctionsLibrary")
import ClassA
import ClassB
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, thank you! BUT when hovering above "import ClassA" in the code PyCharm complains: "No module named ClassA" even though I can use ClassA. Why is this?

Comment: For answering to your question, i need more something. A part of your code, full sentence of the error message.

Comment: This would be the full error message then: "No module named ClassDatabase less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't.
Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases.
Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."

Comment: @user1455613, include like this.

Comment: @RafaelVidal Well what do you mean, the code is the same? Still the same "problem". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variable PYTHONPATH like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/FunctionsLibrary:/path/to/Project\ A
```

And after this python will search in this directory too.

If you use virtualenv you can place this export to "activate" file or you can set environment variable using PyCharm(see in settings).
I prefer using "activate" file